# Creating recursive type in Haskell GADTs

Tags: haskell, programming-languages, type-theory

Taking the following code as an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Example where

data SomeType a where
    MkInt :: Int -> SomeType Int
    MkStr :: String -> SomeType String
    MkRec :: [(String, TypeUnion a)] -> SomeType ???

type TypeUnion a = Either (SomeType Int) (Either (SomeType String) (SomeType ???))
```

In this example, `???` should satisfy that `??? = μX. [(String, TypeUnion a)]`. Because the type parameter `a` in the inner layer of `???` is different from the outer layer, I thought it is infeasible to solve this problem by using simple recursion.

I wonder if there is a way in Haskell I can define such type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always possible to use explicit recursion:

```
newtype Fix f = In { out :: f (Fix f) }
```

Now `Fix SomeType` is the fixpoint of `SomeType`, modulo explicit wrapping/unwrapping.

Comment: Ah, I forgot this! I've learned explicit recursion before but it didn't occur to me when trying to solve this problem :(. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: so how will `MkRec` type look like? how will `TypeUnion`?

Comment: @WillNess Maybe fill in the first blank with `Union a`, and the second blank with `Fix SomeType`? I consider the type parameter in GADTs phantom, so without the exact intention, I cannot determine the answer.

Comment: @pe200012: Note that this type is available in [`Data.Fix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fix-0.3.1/docs/Data-Fix.html), and pattern synonyms can also be quite useful to make the wrapping & unwrapping less noisy when working with `Fix` and similar tools like `Free`.